# Fetch data from a different class in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have to start by informing that I am primarily a Designer by profession and very new to coding.

So while exploring flutter and experimenting few things I have got stuck in a weird place. Logically i feel this shouldn't have been so difficult but I am stuck (i guess there should be very simple way but i am frustrated and hence taking help here).

I have tried to get solution with the minimum knowledge that i have. i have tried shared pref tutorials, route tutorials.. all those solutions basically pass data from screen 1 to screen 2 when you click on a button on Screen1.

**What im looking for is when I click a button on Screen 2, i want to fetch a value from Screen 1 without leaving screen 2**

Let me share the image to give an example (my file has got so complicated that i dont know how i can paste all the 7 dart files that i have created, hence sharing the idea of the app that i am trying to build)

[Basic flow/screens of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAty5.png)

On screen 1 
I have a int *countValue;* variable which increments on click of a button, which is displayed on the screen

You can click on Donate button, which resets countValue to 0 while saving that value in int *totalDonation;*.

On Screen 2
I have a *redeemValue* variable set to say 1000; I also have a Redeem button, on click of Redeem button I want to decrease the redeemValue by int *totalDonation;*
something like
*redeemValue = redeemValue-totalDonation;*

But I am not able to fetch the information of *totalDonation* from Screen 1 while staying on Screen 2.

Possible solutions

1. As and when *totalDonation* is updated on Screen1, i want to pass the value to Screen2 and store it in *totalDonation* which can be used when ever i want

or

2. When i click on Redeem button, i want to call a function which does the calculation, again it needs value of totalDonation

Sorry if its too dumb of a question and sorry for not posting the code.

ps - Oh i knew coding was NOT easy.. but I have realised its way way way super difficult/complicated to code compared to design :)

Comment: It's called as maintaining state of the application, checkout this article https://medium.com/@agungsurya/basic-state-management-in-google-flutter-6ee73608f96d this might will help you.

Answer (score 0):

create a class and initialise your data as static variables

```
class Base{
 static  int  countValue;
 static  int  redeemValue;
 static  int  totalDonation;
}
```

On Screen1: Update the variables

```
Base.totalDoantion = 123; 
Base.countValue = 1;
```

On Screen2: get The data

```
int calucaltion = Base.totalDonation + Base.countValue; //example
```